# In Pine Script v4, how do I set a resolution type input so the default value is "Same as chart"

Tags: pine-script, trading, pine-script-v4

Using Pine Script v4, the input function with `type=input.resolution` has an option in the dropdown for "Same as chart". I would like to set the `defval` default value property so that this option comes up as the default.

For example:

```
//@version=4
chartResolution = input(defval="Same as chart", type=input.resolution, title="Time Resolution")
```

Generates an error that "Same as chart" is not an option. I've also tried setting defval to 0 and "0".

When I set defval to a valid value (such as "60" for 1 hour), the option for "Same as chart" is in the dropdown, at the top of the list, as shown here:

- [image: input.resolution options for input type]

What value needs to be assigned to the input function `defval` argument to get the "Same as chart" option to show up by default?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An empty string is seen as the "Same as Chart" option:

```
//@version=4
study("My Script")
i1 = input("", type = input.resolution)
plot(close)
```

Comment: Perfect. I'm a little mystified that I didn't try that... Thanks!